# Full Calendar using angularJS which contains year, month, week

Tags: angularjs

Full Calendar I need to display in my web page. I need a complete steps in an AngularJS.

1. Display UI calendar - full calendar
2. Populate events
3. providing actions for events.

As am a beginner for an AngularJS I need complete information

If you have idea please tell me the proper steps. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a cool full calendar: http://bootstrap-calendar.azurewebsites.net/

Comment: @Sangeetha have you seen my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this Bootstrap Full Calendar

<kbd>**[Working Demo](http://jsbin.com/xucarixo/1/edit)**</kbd>

[image]

**script**

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="app">
  <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.10/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.11.0.js"></script>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>

<div ng-controller="DatepickerDemoCtrl">
  <b>Selected date is:</b> <em>{{dt | date:'dd-MM-yyyy' }}

    <h4>Full calendar.</h4>
    <div style="display:inline-block; min-height:290px;">
        <datepicker ng-model="dt" min-date="minDate" show-weeks="true" class="well well-sm"></datepicker>
    </div>
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look into the angular ui bootstrap datepicker.

Here is a link: http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

It should provide all the functionality you need.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I want to display full calendar. Not date picker.

Comment: There is a full calendar mode for the datepicker